# Multiple tqdm progress bars with on different processes

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, progress-bar, tqdm

I am trying to create multiple tqdm progress bars which are run by different processes. E.g. 5 processes -> 5 bars -> all in parallel. I managed to achieve something similar. All 5 bars are spawned, however it also starts spawning some extra already existing and dead progress bars. Another problem is that once the working progress bar completes, it disappears.

```
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm
import concurrent.futures


def _loop_sleep(item, tqdm_pos):
    for _ in tqdm(
        range(1000), 
        total=1000, desc=f'Running {item}', position=tqdm_pos
    ):
        sleep(1)

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for item, tqdm_pos in zip(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], [0, 2, 4, 6]):
        executor.submit(
            _loop_sleep,
            item, tqdm_pos
        )
        sleep(1)
```